# Addin $ to JSON element name - JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I am using Jbuilder to generate JSON to feed to a data visualisation toolkit. I need to have a color element with a "$" prefix - something like:

```
"data": {
          "$color": "#222",
        }
```

My jbuilder file currently looks like:

```
json.children principle.nf_permissions_p do |json, permission|
    json.(permission, :id, :name)
    json.data do |json|
            json.color "#000"
    end
end
```

I need to add the $ sign before color. Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json.children principle.nf_permissions_p do |json, permission|
    json.(permission, :id, :name)
    json.data do |json|
        json.set! '$color', "#000"
    end
end
```